# How to keep update the files using PYTHON

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import os 
import glob
import CameraID
files = glob.glob('/tmp/image/*.png')
count = 1
while (count==1):
    for image in files:
        if ( not os.path.isfile(image)):
             print("Error: %s file not found" %image)
        else:
            print("Sending file %s ..." % image)
            print CameraID.run()
            print os.remove(image)
```

When I put the while loop, it will keep run and look for the old file instead the latest file. Anybody can help?

Comment: put also the `glob` command in the while loop (and before the for-loop)? Then it will find new files

Comment: And don't forget to terminate your `while` loop somehow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

moves the line:

```
files = glob.glob('/tmp/image/*.png')
```

into the `while loop` to keep that updated